# Javascript Regex: How to detect if a url is of the form http://<any string without a dot>.one.two.com?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use regex in a JavaScript function to return true if the url is of the form:

`http://<any string without a dot>.one.two.com`

and false otherwise?

for example it would return true for the following:

`http://helloworld.one.two.com , http://poop.one.two.com , etc.`

for example, it would return false for

`http://rawr.zero.one.two.com , http://two.com , etc.`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^http:\/\/[^.]*\.one\.two\.com$/`

Comment: You don't have to escape `.` inside a character class.

Comment: This would also match [http://example.one.two.common.example.org](http://jsfiddle.net/qsddz/)

Comment: @FelixKling true, but it does work, still I've edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^http:\/\/[^.]+\.one\.two\.com/
```

Comment: This won't work, the `.` need to be escaped or they'll match any character, so `http://testing.one-two.com` would match.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^http:\/\/[^\.]+\.one\.two\.com$/
```

The $ at the end is imparative or http://something.one.two.com.blah would also match.